# How do I build lambdas in different languages using AWS CDK Pipelines

Tags: devops, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

I'm setting up a CDK project that have some lambdas in Javascript and Python, I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to build these functions as I would normally pass the build command like this:

```
// Install dependencies, build and run cdk synth
commands: [
   'npm ci',
   'npm run build',
   'npx cdk synth'
]
```

or

```
buildCommand: 'npm run build'
```

The only thing I can think of is to create a **build.sh** file inside each lambda, for the ones in JS I'd add `npm run build` and for the ones in Python `pip install -r requirements.txt` but I don't really know if this is a good practice and if there's a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: Looks like your writing your CDK code in JS/TS, correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Bundling docker container. You can

- either configure the bundling yourself using the [bundling option for Code.fromAsset()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3-assets.AssetOptions.html#bundling)
- or use the [PythonFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-python.PythonFunction.html) and [NodejsFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda-nodejs.NodejsFunction.html) constructs which provide standard bundling for Python and Node.js, respectively.

[This AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/devops/building-apps-with-aws-cdk/) gives some more examples for bundling.